# How to display all values checked in a checkbox using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<form action="/decide_start_session" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name = "subject" value = "NetPresentValue" checked> Net Present Value
    <input type="checkbox" name = "subject" value = "FamaFrench" checked> Fama French
    <%= submit_tag("Start session", class: "btn btn-success") %>
</form>


puts params[:subject]
```

I have the first part in my view and the second line in my controller in my Rails app. If a user selects both checkboxes,  the Rails console only returns the last item checked instead of all of them together. Any idea on how I can fix this (show all the checkboxes in the console)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the name attribute of checkboxes to `subject[]` and remove spaces around `=` in your html, then checked values will be passed to the controller as array.

```
<form action="/decide_start_session" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="NetPresentValue" checked> Net Present Value
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="FamaFrench" checked> Fama French   
</form>
```

Then you can do this in your controller:

```
puts params[:subject].inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `name="subject[]"` and then you will get an array of selected values in `params[:subject]`